# makefile:4: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

This is my makefile:

```
all:ll

ll:ll.c   
  gcc  -c  -Wall -Werror -02 c.c ll.c  -o  ll  $@  $<

clean :
  \rm -fr ll
```

When I try to `make clean` or `make make`, I get this error:

```
:makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can use .RECIPEPREFIX to change the character make uses. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#Special-Variables

Comment: How was this not closed as a duplicate??? Possible duplicate of [Make error: missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)

Comment: In the mcedit "Options -> General" make shure that "Fake half tabs" do not have "X" in square brackets before that option.

Comment: In vim, use: ```Ctrl+V + Tab```

Answer (score 1634, accepted):

make defines a [tab is required to start each recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction).  All actions of every rule are identified by tabs.  If you prefer to prefix your recipes with a character other than tab, you can set the .RECIPEPREFIX variable to an alternate character.

To check, I use the command `cat -e -t -v makefile_name`.

It shows the presence of tabs with `^I` and line endings with `$`.  Both are vital to ensure that dependencies end properly and tabs mark the action for the rules so that they are easily identifiable to the make utility.

Example:

```bash
Kaizen ~/so_test $ cat -e -t -v  mk.t
all:ll$      ## here the $ is end of line ...                   
$
ll:ll.c   $
^Igcc  -c  -Wall -Werror -02 c.c ll.c  -o  ll  $@  $<$ 
## the ^I above means a tab was there before the action part, so this line is ok .
 $
clean :$
   \rm -fr ll$
## see here there is no ^I which means , tab is not present .... 
## in this case you need to open the file again and edit/ensure a tab 
## starts the action part
```

Comment: "cat -e -t -v  makefile_name" is the best thing. Ever. I kept staring at the screen, seeing what looked like a tab, totally missing that it is the ONE LINE in the entire file which used spaces instead of a hard tab.

Comment: When copy/pasting from one makefile to another using the vi (or vim) editor be sure not to accidentally grab the ~ (tilde) line indicating end of file. A real ~ looks like a vi marker and will cause the "*** missing separator. Stop." error. This may seem obvious but when it happens accidentally it's far from evident. See [my blog commentary](http://skycoast.us/pscott/archives/000071.html) for more information.

Comment: `-v` option for `cat` command is redundant here because `-e` means `-vE` and `-t` means `-vT`.

Comment: It's no more "stupid" than Python needing whitespace for control flow, or C needing identifiers made up of certain characters, or English needing vowels. It's just a rule.

Comment: Perhaps it has changed at some point, but using 4 spaces works just as well.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen no, it has never changed and no, it does not work just as well.

Comment: be aware that Make is also temperamental when it comes to syntax and whitespace. I managed to fix this error by putting a space between `ifeq` and the `(` in my Makefile. plenty of ways to stump a beginner

Comment: `cat -e -t -v  Makefile` can be substituted with `cat -A Makefile` which is equivalent to `cat  -vET Makefile`

Comment: Be aware that as of GNU make 3.82 (released in 2010), you can use `.RECIPEPREFIX` to redefine the recipe introduction character to use something different than TAB.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-_002eRECIPEPREFIX-_0028change-the-recipe-prefix-character_0029

Comment: If you are using vim, and are using expandtab to insert spaces when you hit tab key, then in insert mode use Ctrl+v followed by Tab to enter actual tab character.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have to eyeball the entire file to find "the one line" that uses spaces instead of a TAB.  Make tells you _exactly_ which line is the problem.  An error like `Makefile:4: *** missing separator` means the problem is on line 4 of the file `Makefile`.

Answer (score 127):

On VS Code, just click the "Space: 4" on the downright corner and change it to tab when editing your Makefile.

Comment: VS Code recognised that my 'common.mk' file, extracted from a no-suffix 'Makefile' was a make file, and highlighted it correctly - but quietly started indenting with spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: This worked when I selected "Convert Indentation to Tabs"

Comment: It worked with "Convert Indentation to Tabs"

Answer (score 64):

By default, you should always write command after a <kbd>Tab</kbd> and not white space. [This can be changed to another character with `.RECIPEPREFIX` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction).

This applies to `gcc` line (line #4) in your case. You need to insert tab before `gcc`.

Also replace `\rm -fr ll` with `rm -fr ll`. Insert tabs before this command too.

Comment: To be very clear, there must be a hard TAB character as the first character in each logical recipe line.  After the TAB, you can add any kind of whitespace you want.

Comment: should the tabspace be equal to 2 or 4? in /.vimrc set tabstop = 2 or 4?

Comment: @RahulReddy how an editor displays a tab has nothing to do with whether there is or is not a tab character in the configuration.

Answer (score 23):

#### TLDR;

makefile syntax can be quirky
if you want a line of code to be interpreted as `make` code it must only be indented with **spaces**.
if you want a line of code to be interpreted as `bash` code it must only be indented with **tabs**

```
sometask:
  ifeq ($FOO,bar)  // this is make code. only spaces
    echo "foobar"  // this is bash code. only tabs
  endif            // again, this is make code. only spaces
```

technically its the leading indentation that dictates the interpreter.

Comment: It's working for me in reverse, like tab for make and space for bash

Comment: Do you have any reference on this ?

Answer (score 20):

The solution for `PyCharm` would be to install a `Makefile support` plugin:

1. Open `Preferences` (`cmd + ,`)
2. Go to `Plugins` -> `Marketplace`
3. Search for `Makefile support`, install and restart the IDE.

This should fix the problem and provide a syntax for a makefile.

Comment: This also helps in GoLand

Comment: I find IDE real matters. Tab edition is not supported in pycharm. When I change to ATOM, TAB input works.

Comment: If your IDE is automatically indenting with spaces, you might be able to enter a unicode tab with \u09  which on some desktop environments for Linux can be done with Ctrl+Shift+U then typing '09'. " ". It isn't very fun though.

Answer (score 16):

Using [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) to fix the tabs automagically:

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

[Makefile]
indent_style = tab
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @TejasShetty it's not meant to work for a person but for the IDE ;-) If it doesn't work for you, you need to enable it in your IDE.

Comment: Work on intelliJ

Answer (score 13):

When you created a Makefile in VSCode, You should set the Tab Size: 4[image].

Answer (score 9):

Its pretty old question but still I would like say about one more option using `vi/vim` editor to visualize the tabs. If you have `vi/vim` installed then open a `Makefile` (e.g. `vim Makefile`) and enter `:set list`. This will show number of tabs inserted as below,

```
 %-linux: force$
^I@if [ "$(GCC_VERSION)" = "2.96" ] ; then \$
^I^Iecho ===== Generating build tree for legacy $@ architecture =====; \$
^I^I$(CONFIGURE) $(CWD) $@ legacy; \$
^Ielse \$
^I^Iecho ===== Generating build tree for $@ architecture =====; \$
^I^I$(CONFIGURE) $(CWD) $@; \$
^Ifi$
^Icd build-$@;make$
```

Answer (score 8):

You started line 4 with "space,space" instead of "tab" - nothing else.

Answer (score 8):

For me 2023 only this worked.
[image]

After this everything worked fine.

Comment: Michael's comment is absolutely correct, folks should turn on the tab indicated in VS code.

Answer (score 4):

The key point was "HARD TAB"

1. Check whether you used TAB instead of whitespace
2. Check your `.vimrc` for `set tabstop=X`

Answer (score 4):

If anyone of you are using a product from Intellij, the solution for this it's the following:

1. Go to Preferences > Editor > Code Style
2. here you need to select the file type related to your problem. But most probably you need to select `Other File Types`.
3. In the tab opened mark the checkbox for `Use tab character` and be careful, `Tab size` and `Indent` values must be 4.

Answer (score 3):

Try with the following **command**.

`perl -pi -e 's/^  */\t/' Makefile`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mcedit for makefile edit. you have to see the following mark.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are here searching how to make the tabs and new lines you added understandable by vim you have to first enable tab in vim.

You can do it using `:set noet` i.e. (to switch from spaces to TAB) before you make your tab additions.

With this command your tabs will look like the other ones (i.e. ^I) and  `*** missing separator.  Stop.` error from make will go away :)

after you make changes you can switch back with `:set et`

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favour and make this a permanent member of your `.editorconfig`, if your editor/IDE supports it (it probably does!)

```
[Makefile]
indent_style = tab
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because tab is replaced by spaces.
To disable this feature go to

**gedit->edit->preferences->editor**

and remove check for

"**replace tab with space**"

Answer (score 1):

If someone ever comes across this issue with

```
*** missing separator.  Stop.
```

during the build, they should double-check their file system path to the sources, it should not contain special characters like "#"

e.g. path

```
/home/user/#my_sources/
```

might be invalid

Comment: Could you please give more details?

Comment: The issue generally happens when you use spaces in place of Tab. In most editors there will be a setting to change the Tab to spaces conversion. That need's to be disabled or one can use notepad++ or sublime text to replace all spaces before rules with tabs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you guys mean and what details you want. My answer is related to the path to the sources, in my case, the problem was that the file system path contained the special character "#" and the problem was not related to the content of the sources itself and there was no mention of that potential problem in other answers. The problem with spaces is already elaborated on in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing your Makefile in eclipse:

```
Windows-> Preferences->General->Editor->Text Editors->Show Whitespace Characters -> Apply
```

Or use the shortcut shown below.

Tab will be represented by gray ">>" and Space will be represented by gray "." as in figure below.

[image]