# Makefile:1: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

I'm creating a project on c and when i make my Makefile and try to run it it gives me this error:

```
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

My makefile code is:

```
CC=gcc
OBJ=./objetos
INC=./include
FON=./aqsFonte
BIB=./bibliotecas
OPBIB=-lBiblioteca
ProjetoFinal: libFinal.a
    $(CP) $(FON)/ProjetoFinal.c -I$(INC) -L$(BIB) $(OPBIB) -o ProjetoFinal

Bibliotecas.a: Caminho.o Libs_Defines.o Matrizes.o Proc_Imagens.o Vetores.o
    ar -q $(BIB)/libFinal.a Caminho.o ibs_Defines.o Matrizes.o Proc_Imagens.o Vetores.o

Caminho.o:
    $(CP) $(FON)/Caminho.c -o Caminho.o
Libs_Defines.o :
    $(CP) $(FON)/Libs_Defines.c -o Libs_Defines.o
Matrizes.o:
    $(CP) $(FON)/Matrizes.c -o Matrizes.o
Proc_Imagens.o:
    $(CP) $(FON)/Proc_Imagens.c -o Proc_Imagens.o
Vetores.o:
    $(CP) $(FON)/Vetores.c -o Vetores.o
```

Also, it's all tabbed correctly I guess.

Comment: maybe the space after Libs_Defines.o ?

Comment: what about line endings?

Comment: Makefile is usually very picky about space and tabs

Comment: Better upload the file zipped somewhere.

Comment: you have leading spaces instead of tab..

Comment: @devnull the code highlighter of SO renders tabs as spaces.

Comment: I removed all spaces from the endings, removed the onee after Libs_Defines and all tabs are tabs, not spaeces, still gives me error on line 1

Comment: @JoãoMiranda could you post your makefile on http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kDnsjFxi)

Comment: @JoãoMiranda these are spaces, not tabs. your editor is messing with you. :)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin do you know one that doesnt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makefile:4: \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's a tabs problem. Some text editors may replace tabs with white spaces, make sure you use a proper text editor that doesn't mess it up. Open your makefile in vi or any other rudimentary editor, and rewrite that makefile.

Note that after each target rule, **one single tab** must be placed in the beginning of the line. Everything that comes after that tab is passed on to the shell (there can be more tabs, spaces, and whatever you want, but keep in mind that there must be a tab in the beginning of the line).

Comment: I'm using the stock text editor on mac, do you recommend another?

Comment: It's not true that only _one single tab_ is allowed.  The rule is that the first character in the line must be a TAB character.  After that, you can do whatever you want for the rest of the line (more tabs, spaces, whatever).  Whatever is there is passed to the shell to be executed.

Comment: @JoãoMiranda I don't know, never been on a Mac, but I'm sure there are other possibilities

Comment: @MadScientist you're right, I edited my answer to be a little more clear. Thanks.

Comment: I faced the "missing separator" error when using [conditionals in make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html). It seems you would get the error when you forget to add a space between the `ifeq` and the `(` so that it looks like `ifeq (` and not like `ifeq(`. Hope make was a little more clear about this!

Comment: I got this error, `warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored`, when I had a `makefile` containing a row like: `-include some_object_file.o` (which apparently is WRONG). Once I changed it to `<TAB>-include some_object_file.o`, the error went away. THANKS! (Here, <TAB> should of course be replaced by a proper TAB in the text editor. - You will definitely want a text editor which clearly displays whether you have SPACES or a TAB.)

Answer (score 23):

can you try running -

```
perl -pi -e 's/^  */\t/' Makefile
```

(after saving a backup of course)

Comment: Did you open/save the Makefile in an editor before rerunning it?

Comment: Best answer - and Yes avoid touching file with editor after this perl command prior to running make

Comment: just running the above fixed the problem, IDE I am using is IntelliJ. Thanks

Comment: yeah, life saver there on the perl! worked for me as well!

Answer (score 8):

It can also be due to a missing colon between .PHONY and your targets

```
.PHONY all 
all:
<tab><do this>
```

throws error
while below works fine

```
.PHONY: all 
all:
<tab><do this>
```

Answer (score 4):

make is very sensitive on the way rules and targets are indented. The error you post is usually caused by indenting the rule of a target with spaces instead of a single tab.

for example:

```
target:
    do stuff
```

will error, but

```
target:
<tab>do stuff
```

will not.

Comment: It's all tabbed, is there another reason for this error? And why does it shows on line 1?

Comment: @JoãoMiranda sometimes, text editors insert spaces, even when you press the tab key. are you **really sure** these are tab characters? Try firing up the simplest possible text editor on your system and have a look if the characters are really tabs.

Answer (score 4):

I was writing C++ in **vscode** and faced the same problem.

The problem was that **vscode** inserts spaces instead of tabs, your text editor might be doing the same but you didn't notice.

If you are using **vscode**, add this line to your `settings.json` file:

```
// Will control if the editor will insert spaces for tabs. values = <"auto" | true | false>
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
```

If that didn't work, try opening your **Makefile** from another text editor e.g(Vim, Notepad, ...), then insert tabs from there, that should insert the tab correctly unless you have the same issue with that text editor too.

---

### Bouns

If you are using **vscode** you can check if the current character is a space or tab by selecting it, then **vscode** will represent:

- tabs: `➙`
- spaces: `•`

---

### [image: Photo that descript how vscode represents spaces and tabs under selection]

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time. VScode is behaving weirdly. When I change the spaces to a tab in VScode it is not taking.I opened my make file in Notepad++ and edited it there. It works.

Answer (score 0):

actually i faced a similar problem 
every thing was right but later i understood
i use g-edit ill tell the solution
edit>preferances>editor tab>uncheck the button (insert spaces instead of tabs)
and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a modern text editor that understands the unicode standard. -- Even if you open an ANSI file in these editors, they'll usually save them back out as UTF-8 -- which is very backwards compatible, except that it places two "invisible" bytes at the beginning of the file, so that other programs will know what format the text is encoded with. -- This is why the "error" is reported on line 1.

If you're using Notepad for Windows, you're in luck, as there is an option to override this behavior and save the file in the "ANSI" format.  Here's how:

1. File -> Save As
2. Change "Save as type" to "All Files".
3. Find the exact location of the Makefile (sometimes, save as puts you in a different directory, I don't know why this happened but it kept happening to me).
4. Change the file name from "Makefile" to "Makefile." -- the trailing period is important (without it, it will be saved as "Makefile.txt", even when "All Files" is selected).
5. Change "Encoding" from "UTF-8" to "ANSI".

   [image: Save with ANSI Encoding]

Answer (score 0):

I just meet the same problem when compliling my source code with auto generated  gcc makefile.

I finally found it was caused by the utf-8 BOM characters at the beginning of the makefile.These charaters are invisible in some text editors.

so try save the file as utf-8 without BOM.

Comment: and how do you see those invisible characters?

Comment: vscode got an update allowing users to see those invisible characters