# Trouble compiling a Makefile using g++

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, g++, clang

I have the text of a Makefile, and I am trying to compile it and produce a .e executable file. I am trying to compile it in g++, but I am having some difficulty. Please note I have a MacBook Pro running Mavericks.

I have tried two methods--the first was to open up Xcode and make a new .cpp file. I then copied the Makefile text into the empty .cpp file and saved it as Makefile.g++. In the Mac terminal, I then executed

```
g++ Makefile.g++
```

It returns the error

```
d: warning: ignoring file Makefile.g++, file was built for unsupported file format (      
0x23 0x20 0x47 0x65 0x6E 0x65 0x72 0x69 0x63 0x20 0x70 0x69 0x6D 0x63 0x20 0x67 ) which  
is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): Makefile.g++

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_main", referenced from:
 implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I then tried saving it as Makefile.cpp, and executing

```
g++ Makefile.cpp
```

I then get the error

```
Makefile.cpp:11:3: error: invalid preprocessing directive
# Generic pimc g++ makefile
  ^
Makefile.cpp:13:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
CC      = g++
^~
Makefile.cpp:13:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'g'
CC      = g++
          ^
Makefile.cpp:16:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive
#CC = /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.7
 ^
Makefile.cpp:17:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive
#LD = /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.7
 ^
Makefile.cpp:33:3: error: invalid preprocessing directive
# Edit below to include details on your specific host
  ^
Makefile.cpp:116:3: error: invalid preprocessing directive
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^
Makefile.cpp:119:3: error: invalid preprocessing directive
# Link
  ^
Makefile.cpp:123:3: error: invalid preprocessing directive
# Compile
  ^
Makefile.cpp:127:3: error: invalid preprocessing directive
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^
Makefile.cpp:130:22: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
$(RM) $(PROG) $(OBJS)
                     ^
                     ;
11 errors generated.
```

What am I doing incorrect? Can the Makefile not run on my machine, or is it something to do with my commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoa there cowboy! You've told `g++` that `Makefile.cpp` is a `C++` source file, not a makefile. `mv Makefile.cpp Makefile`, then run `make`. That should help out.

Your fundamental source of confusion is that you are under the impression that you should *compile a makefile*, but makefiles are a set of *rules for compiling source files*. Once you get the hang of things, the command `g++ Makefile` will look horrifying to you, because you'll know that `make` *invokes* `g++`.

Comment: I ran mv Makefile.cpp Makefile, and no error came up. However, I then tried running make -f Makefile, and I get the following error: Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: Ok, then you have a bug in your makefile. Edit the question, post your makefile in its entirety, then post the result of `make --just-print`.

Comment: `cat -A Makefile` will show you if you have tabs/spaces problems.

Comment: Okay--when I run that, I get                                                     cat: illegal option -- A
usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]. I can't post the original makefile because the explicit code wasn't made by me, and is private.

Comment: Ok check this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936337/makefile1-missing-separator-stop