# How to convert bin file into a text file?

Tags: r

I have stored my output in a bin file called `vectors.bin`. Now I need to convert it to a text file as I am not able to open it. I have used the following code:

```
./convertvec bin2txt vectors.bin output.txt
```

But it is giving me the error:

> bash: ./convertvec: No such file or directory

**UPDATE**

I have gotten further after working with the suggestions in the comments and can run:

```
R CMD BATCH --slave vectors.bin output.txt
```

which creates an `output.txt` file. But, in the `output.txt`, it is giving message as:

> Error: unexpected numeric constant in "987 200"
>   Execution halted

Comment: it seems like you have not installed convertvec properly. https://github.com/marekrei/convertvec

Comment: I have tried using this code. But I am getting the error: makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: Have you modified anything in the makefile? if you just do this: `git clone https://github.com/marekrei/convertvec.git ; cd convertvec ; make`, it should work. If it doesn't, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936337/makefile1-missing-separator-stop

Comment: I have done the same. But I am again getting error: bash: Git: command not found. I am using Centos OS

Comment: you should install git : `sudo yum install git`

Comment: Can anybody give any other answer?