# insmod error, invalid module format on debian 9.5

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, beagleboneblack, insmod

i have an original module in debian 10 on a beaglebone black and now i am running it on debian 9.5 with a different kernel.
So when i try to insert the module i get this error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module gpio_test.ko: Invalid module format
```

My current kernel version is:

```
uname -r 4.4.155-ti-rt-r155
```

I have tried to follow the solution posted here but with no luck: [insmod error: inserting './hello.ko': -1 Invalid module format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379013/insmod-error-inserting-hello-ko-1-invalid-module-format)

my current Makefile contents are:

```
obj-m+=gpio_test.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

when i run this make file i get this error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.155-ti-rt-r155/build/ M=/home/machinekit/BeagleBoneBlack-Program-Files/LKM_Interrupt_Practice/LED_Button_IRQ modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.155-ti-rt-r155/build/: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: A module built for one kernel cannot be inserted into another kernel. You need to build the module against the kernel you want to load it. Building a module requires **kernel sources** to be available. And `-C` parameter should point to the sources tree of the kernel.

Comment: @Tsyvarev isnt `make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules` already pointing to the source tree?

Comment: It’s pointing to non-existing folder.

Comment: Is there a `linux-headers-4.4.155-ti-rt-r155` package you can install?

Comment: @IanAbbott hello, my current struggle is finding one. Even the command `apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)` does not find any

Comment: How do you obtain that kernel (`4.4.155-ti-rt-r155`)? The way of obtaining its sources depends on that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I got the kernel with this command `./update_kernel.sh --ti-rt-channel --lts-4_4` and i followed the tutorial from this link: [link](https://machinekoder.com/machinekit-debian-stretch-beaglebone-black) check under "Install the RT Kernel"  section

Comment: Hm, as far as I understand that tutorial tells only about obtaining of the **kernel image**. But says nothing about obtaining sources (build tree) for that image.

Comment: @programmer25 The page you linked to contains a [link](https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#BBW.2FBBB_.28All_Revs.29_Machinekit) to a ready made MachineKit system image based on the 4.19.106-bone-rt-r49 kernel. Does that image contain the kernel headers needed to build external kernel modules?

Comment: @IanAbbott Hi, i have tried that as well but i don't think it has it either since i still had the same issue with it. I am now currently trying to build a kernel which already has the PREEMPT RT patch. I was told that if i built the kernel than the linux headers would be there. But i ran into some compiler issues: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600175/cross-compiler-error-for-arm-beaglebone-black)