# cross compiler error for ARM Beaglebone black

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I am trying to cross compile for a beaglebone black from a desktop running Ubuntu:

```
Linux DESKTOP-4UIP5QG 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #836-Microsoft Mon May 05 16:04:00 PST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The target machine is a beaglebone black:

```
Linux beaglebone 4.19.94-ti-r42 #1buster SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 31 19:38:29 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I am currently following a tutorial that will help me do this but i cant seem to find the compiler version that they are using: https://www.itdev.co.uk/blog/building-linux-kernel-cross-compiling-beaglebone-black

i have tried to install the compiler with:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

but i receive the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

So i then tried to install a gcc-arm compiler with

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm*
```

but after install this and attempting to compile with:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- bb.org_defconfig
```

I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
init/Kconfig:17: syntax error
init/Kconfig:16: invalid option
./scripts/clang-version.sh: 15: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
./scripts/gcc-plugin.sh: 11: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found 
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:104: bb.org_defconfig] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:534: bb.org_defconfig] Error 2
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you have installed, and was did actually get installed when you did that `apt-get install gcc-arm*`?

Comment: @domen My Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS and i installed gcc-arm with that command based off a possible solution from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180185/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi-command-not-found) Its not really  explicit

Comment: That solution is quite old, and also mentions 32-bit libraries. Is that relevant in your case? And, what was actually installed? Does `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` actually exist now (and it's a case of libraries missing) or is now there a compiler with some other name?

Comment: I am not sure if it exist, I am willing to switch compiler versions to get the job done, But then its a matter of the correct syntax in order to do so

Comment: Just installed it yesterday on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: you can install one of the many pre-builts though

Comment: Im using a Ubuntu application on a windows 10 machine, im not sure if thats whats causing my issues

Answer (score 3):

A more deterministic way of pointing to the exact toolchain you want to use is to provide its full prefix when setting `CROSS_COMPILE`. This will avoid possible path-related errors, and the information on which exact toolchain was used for building will be embedded in your build script.

Full example - installing official Arm gcc 9.2.0 toolchain and retrieving/building u-boot 20.04 for the beaglebone black (use your own u-boot and defconfig):

```
# gcc 9.2.0
mkdir -p /opt/arm/9
wget 'https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/9.2-2019.12/binrel/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz?revision=64186c5d-b471-4c97-a8f5-b1b300d6594a&la=en&hash=5E9204DA5AF0B055B5B0F50C53E185FAA10FF625'
tar Jxf gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz -C /opt/arm/9

# u-boot
wget https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/archive/v2020.04.tar.gz
tar zxf v2020.04.tar.gz
cd u-boot-2020.04
make CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi- ARCH=arm mrproper am335x_evm_defconfig all
```

The commands above should work on a native x86_64 Linux, an x86_64 Linux running under VMWare or VirtualBox on Windows, and WSl/WSL2 Windows Linux Subsystems on a Windows 64 bit system.

This being said, if you want to investigate your specific issue, you verify which  toolchain you installed:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep gcc-arm
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf                         install
```

If there are not outputs, you may not have installed what you think you installed. You can search what are the packages available on your system using `apt-cache search`:

```
sudo apt-cache search gcc-arm-linux
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf - GNU C compiler for the armhf architecture
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi - GNU C compiler for the armel architecture
```

Install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Verify the compiler is there:

```
which arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

I would however recommend to stick with an Arm or Linaro toolchain rather than a distro-delivered one.

Answer (score 1):

A `sudo apt update` and `apt upgrade` allowed me to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

Comment: Glad to read that. If, and only if, this was my answer above that made you think of the missing `sudo`, you may want to accept it.