# IGB_UIO Crashed sudddenly

Tags: dpdk

My igb_uio driver of dpdk crashed suddenly. It was working fine. Then suddenly it stopped working and wont load up. It gives the following error, any ideas?

Error ->  [image]
[image: IGB_UIO INFO]

Comment: please add result for `modinfo [path to igb_uio]` and `uname -r`

Comment: Added the result in question area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux version you are running and Kernel module `igb_uio` are different. Rebuild the DPDK kernel module to work for current Linux.

Note: I highly recommend to least do basic debug for linux kernel build. refer
[stackoverflow link describing module error format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379013/insmod-error-inserting-hello-ko-1-invalid-module-format)