# Makefile:9: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a simple makefile, am getting missing separator:

```
CC =  g++
CFLAGS =  -Wall -g

all:  compile 

compile:  array.cpp
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  array.cpp

run:  ./result.out
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makefile:4: \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
CC = g++ 
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

all: compile

compile: array.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) array.cpp

run: 
    ./result.out
```

And make sure you use tabs for indentation, not spaces.

Comment: "And make sure you use tabs for indentation, not spaces." ==> this is what I need in my case! thank you