# Unable to debug the makefile. Makefile:9: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: linux, vim, makefile

I have written the following Makefile:

```
CC='/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/bin/i586-wrs-linux-gnu-gcc --sysroot=/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/sysroot'
IDIR =../../../include
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

LDIR =../../../../../../../../.debug/lib.out/public/
LIBS= -lmylib1 -lmylib2 -lmylib3

myexec: my_code.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myexec my_code.c
```

It throws error:

```
Makefile:9: *** missing separator. Stop
```

I looked at a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop). It says there can a problem with a tab. I double checked the code. I am using a tab and not spaces. However when I run

```
cat -e -t -v  Makefile
```

I get the following, that implies there is no tab before `$CC`.

```
CC='/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/bin/i586-wrs-linux-gnu-gcc --sysroot=/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/sysroot'$
IDIR =../../../include$
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)$
$
LDIR =../../../../../../../../.debug/lib.out/public/$
LIBS= -lmylib1 -lmylib2 -lmylib3$
$
myexec: my_code.c$
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myexec my_code.c$
```

I also checked my .vimrc file. I have `set tabstop=4`. I tried removing this, but it rather made the situation worse. It started giving me error: `Makefile:9: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.`
 This is how it looks:

```
syntax on
colorscheme desert
set nocompatible
set number
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set autoindent
set ruler
set spell
set title
set et
set mouse=v
set history=100
set tabstop=4
```

Comment: The `et` option is the culprit. It is short for `expandtab`--just what you _don't_ want. Remove from your `.vimrc`. Then, reenter the `$(CC)` line in your makefile

Comment: @CraigEstey: This makes sense for the asker because they are willing to change their vim configuration. For a lot of users, most of the time the vim configuration is the desired default behavior, but they need an exception for the occasional weird file.

Comment: Adding the line `filetype plugin indent on` makes Vim load filetype-specific settings and thus override your own generic settings with sensible ones.

Comment: @jxh Before there was `.vimrc`, there was the environment variable `EXINIT`. That's what I use/prefer. It solves the problem for weird files because it can be set on a per (e.g.) `xterm` basis. For example, for my own code, I prefer a tabstop of 4 (which I set in `EXINIT` from `.login` or `.bash_profile`). However, for cases when I'm doing a lot of edits for "tab8" files, I open a new `xterm` and I have a shell alias/function that modifies `EXINIT` and sets `ts=8` for that window only (e.g. `t8`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something in your `vim` initializations that prevents correct editing of the Makefile. It appears to be `et`, which is the abbreviation for the `expandtab` setting, which causes each tab character to be expanded to the appropriate number of space characters. <sub>(Thanks to Craig Estey for confirming this.)</sub>

However, you can tell `vim` to not use your init file by using `-u NONE`:

```
vim -u NONE Makefile
```

With that, you should be able to edit in the needed tab character.

Alternatively, you can add this to the bottom of your `.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd FileType make set noet
```

which will disable `expandtab` behavior whenever you edit a Makefile.