# Makefile giving error " missing separator"

Tags: makefile, syntax-error

When I run `make` on `Makefile`. I get the following error:

> Makefile:809: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Here is the Makefile snippet from line 806:

```
.PRECIOUS: Makefile


@ap_include@ 

#
#   ANALYSIS
#

$(LANG1).chunk_rules.dat: $(BASENAME).chunk_rules.dat
    cp $< $@

#
#   GENERATION
#

$(LANG1).autogen.bin: $(BASENAME).$(LANG1).dix
    lt-comp rl $< $@

$(LANG1).gnx.bin: $(BASENAME).$(LANG1).gnx
    matxin-preprocess-generate $< $@

# Tell versions [3.59,3.63) of GNU make to not export all variables.
# Otherwise a system limit (for SysV at least) may be exceeded.
.NOEXPORT:
```

Error is at line 808 or the line starting with "@ap_include".
Here is the link to complete makefile: [Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/abhishekjiitr/a3943dfafbefc4fb07daaef165c4bc58)

Comment: What do you expect `@ap_include@` to do?

Comment: You get that error because that's not legal makefile syntax.

Comment: Can you give me suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you tell me how can I correct it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makefile:4: \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)