# Issue with valgrind in a makefile

Tags: makefile, valgrind

My makefile looks like that and it works but for the valgrind bit. What do I do wrong?

```
all: main

main: main.o tree.o list.o
gcc -o main main.o tree.o list.o

main.o: main.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c11 -O2 -c main.c

tree.o: tree.h tree.c
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c11 -O2 -c tree.c

list.o: list.c list.h
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c11 -O2 -c list.c

clean:
    rm *.o main

valgrid:
    valgrind ./main
```

Error is: makefile:19: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: What's the error you're getting with the `valgrind` target?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop

Comment: Spell `valgrind` consistently — `valgrid` is a different program.  Make the `valgrind` target depend on `main` (you probably don't want to waste your time running `valgrind` on an out of date program): `valgrind: main`.  You're going to want to add flags to Valgrind, at least on occasion.  Use macros: `VALGRIND = valgrind` and `VALGRIND_FLAGS =` (nothing by default), and then the command should become `${VALGRIND} ${VALGRIND_FLAGS} ./main`.  That allows you to run Valgrind with different flags without editing the makefile.