# Makefile error: "Missing separator. Stop."

Tags: makefile, terminal

Trying to compile a Makefile gives me the following error:

```
 Makefile:248: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

The relevant lines in the Makefile (line 248 and nearby lines) are:

```
tar :
    @if test -f espresso.tar.gz ; then /bin/rm espresso.tar.gz ; fi
    # do not include unneeded stuff 
    find ./ -type f | grep -v -e /.svn/ -e'/\.' -e'\.o$$' \
             -e'\.mod$$' -e'\.a$$' -e'\.d$$' -e'\.i$$' -e'\.F90$$' -e'\.x$$' \
         -e'~$$' -e'\./GUI' -e '\./tempdir' | xargs tar rvf espresso.tar
    gzip espresso.tar
```

Where the third line of the command `find` ending with `espresso.tar` is line 248.
I tried following the debug procedure listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop) and issued the command `cat -e -t -v  Makefile`, which gave me the following code:

```
tar :$
^I@if test -f espresso.tar.gz ; then /bin/rm espresso.tar.gz ; fi$
^I# do not include unneeded stuff $
^Ifind ./ -type f | grep -v -e /.svn/ -e'/\.' -e'\.o$$' \$
         -e'\.mod$$' -e'\.a$$' -e'\.d$$' -e'\.i$$' -e'\.F90$$' -e'\.x$$' \$
^I     -e'~$$' -e'\./GUI' -e '\./tempdir' | xargs tar rvf espresso.tar$
^Igzip espresso.tar$
$
```

Sure enough, the ^I character was missing, but from line 247 (weird). So I edited the file to include the tab character and now it says:

```
tar :$
^I@if test -f espresso.tar.gz ; then /bin/rm espresso.tar.gz ; fi$
^I# do not include unneeded stuff $
^Ifind ./ -type f | grep -v -e /.svn/ -e'/\.' -e'\.o$$' \$
^I     -e'\.mod$$' -e'\.a$$' -e'\.d$$' -e'\.i$$' -e'\.F90$$' -e'\.x$$' \$
^I     -e'~$$' -e'\./GUI' -e '\./tempdir' | xargs tar rvf espresso.tar$
^Igzip espresso.tar$
$
```

However the error still persists, which I somewhat expected since the problem wasn't with that line in the first place. I even tried removing all the whitespace from the relevant lines but the error is still there. Not sure if there's a problem with the ^I character. Any help in solving this issue would be appreciated. Thanks!

The full Makefile can be found in the main folder of the download file (direct link to the file [here](http://www.qe-forge.org/gf/download/frsrelease/185/753/espresso-5.1.2.tar.gz))

Comment: There must be some mistake here.  There's nothing wrong with that recipe.  I downloaded your tarball but line 248 of the root makefile is NOT a line in that rule, in that version.  I also ran `make -n` but I got no error message, so the root makefile is not a problem.  So then I ran `make -n` on all the Makefiles in the tarball and got no missing separator errors on any of them.

Comment: You've been told before about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).