# Template ident after generate

Tags: go, makefile, gnu-make, go-templates

I'm generating a `makefile` using GO `text/template`
The template is generated **as expected** (with the right content ) but the problem is that it’s not **indented** with **tabs** and I got errors while running `make` command after generation.

**This is the output of the template:**

```
all: app app_2

DIR = $(PWD)
.PHONY: app
app:
@echo "run module 1"

.PHONY: app_2
app_2:
@echo "run module 2”
```

When I run make I got error "makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.” (This is the line with the first echo”)

If I change the ideation to `tab` (after the file was generated) with `Goland` or `vsCode`, I was able to **run the file successfully** and see the expected output..., any idea how to make it work with go text/template ?

**This is the template**

```
all: {{- range .Load.Proc}} {{.Name}}{{end}}


{{- range .Load.Proc}}
.PHONY: {{.Name}}
{{.Name}}:
    @echo {{.Text}}
{{end}}
```

This is the makefile issue: [makefile:4: *** missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop) but for me it's a problem since I want to generate the file without the need to manually change the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tab characters in the template to produce tabs in the output. To fix the template in the question, replace the spaces before `@echo` with a tab character.

https://play.golang.org/p/c7v6eNsI2Fy

If you cannot put tabs in the template for some reason, then use `{{"\t"}}` to produce a tab in the output:

```
{{"\t"}}echo {{.Text}}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/3B-oIW-aCb4