# Rules of executing shell command in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

When I executed command `make`, I got an error message

> Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.

The command in `Makefile` is:

```
$(shell ./makejce common/jce jce)
```

What's wrong with it?

-------makejce---------

```
#!/bin/bash
FLAGS=""
local_protoc=""
dir0=`pwd`
dir=`pwd`
......

if [ $# -gt 1 ]
then
    mkdir -p $2
    cd $2
    dir=`pwd`
    cd $dir0
fi

cd $1
jce_dir=`pwd`

#sub dir
for d in `ls -d */`
do
    if [ -d $d ]
    then
            cd $d
            for f in `find . -name '*.jce'`
            do  
                    ${local_protoc} ${FLAGS} --dir=${dir} $f
            done
            cd $jce_dir
    fi
done

#current dir
for f in `ls *.jce`
do
    ${local_protoc} ${FLAGS} --dir=${dir} $f
done

cd $dir0
```

-----makefile------

```
......
$(shell ./makejce common/jce jce)
......
```

Comment: This typically occurs when you have target that does not have the ":". But could you give a MWCE ?

Comment: @kebs Do you mean a [mcve]?  (Type `[mcve]` to get that in a comment.)

Comment: @Alfe yep, thanks ! Couln't remember, mixed up" working" and "verifiable"...!

Comment: You're missing a separator.  Indent with tabs.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Where? If I add add a tab before line4, the another error occures:`Makefile:4: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I just want to execute a shell command here.

Comment: not enough info to strictly know what is going on here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makefile:4: \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)

Answer (score 2):

With so little info it looks extremely bizarre (why are you running all the build steps in a shell script then invoking that script with a `shell` makefile function?  The entire point of a makefile is to manage the build steps...) but without more information I'll just answer your specific question:

The make `shell` function works like backticks or `$(...)` in shell scripts: that is it runs the command in a shell and *expands to the stdout of the command*.

In your makefile if you have:

```
$(shell echo hi)
```

then it runs the shell command `echo hi` and expands to the stdout (i.e., `hi`).  Then make will attempt to interpret that as some makefile text, because that's where you have put the function invocation (on a line all by itself).  That's a syntax error because make doesn't know what to do with the string `hi`.

If you want to run a `shell` function then either (a) redirect its output so it doesn't output anything:

```
$(shell ...command... >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

or (b) capture the output somewhere that it won't bother make, such as in a variable like this:

```
_dummy := $(shell ...command...)
```

(by using `:=` here we ensure the `shell` function is evaluated when the makefile is parsed).

Comment: It works! The `makefile` I post is not the whole file. The other command replaced with `......`.