# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. on Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to build my code but I keep getting this 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I assume I need a makefile. How do I get this? Sorry I am a beginner coder

Comment: A `makefile` is a text file that you create and fill with instructions for the compiler on how to build your project. Here's a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770) that shows what a makefile might look like. You can find all sorts of examples and information by searching for `[c] [makefile]` in the search box above. But really you need to find some good documentation.

Comment: suggest reading the MAN page for `make` and since it is such a 'large' feature program, suggest reading the manual, several manual formats are available at: [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual)

Comment: actually, a 'makefile' is instructions to the `make` utility and can pass some commands through to other programs, like the `gcc` compiler

Answer (score 2):

When Using Xcode with C you need to first:
Click File
Click New
Click Project

Select macOS
Select Command Line Tool
Hit Next

Enter a Name for the Program
Enter any organization name you would like
Select C language
Hit Next

Save the file to desired location
Hit Create

Click Main.c on the left column
Enter code (A hello world program is automatically pre written)

To Run Code:
Hit the Play button in the top left

If you get an error, make sure that the scheme is set to your program name and to My Mac. This is located right next to the play and stop button.

Hopefully this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.