# @echo in Makefile always causes error " *** missing separator. Stop."

Tags: makefile, echo, gnu-make, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xv6

I put

```
@echo "============= $(TOOLPREFIX) ================="
```

in line 34 of Makefile of xv6 used by many OS courses, in hope of printing out the value of variable TOOLPREFIX. But I always got error

```
Makefile:37: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

This line is before any target. I tried everything I could, like adding Tab at the beginning of the command, moving the command to everywhere in Makefile, or deleting the symbol @ before echo, but I always got an error no matter what. But if I comment out this command, there is no error. So, how should I correctly print out a variable in this Makefile?

As a side note, if I add Tab at the beginning of the command, the error I got is "Makefile:37: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop." But if I move the @echo command to the bottom of Makefile, "Makefile:287: *** missing separator.  Stop." comes out again.

The environment is Window Subsystem for Linux with ubuntu 20.04 installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makefile:4: \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)

Comment: You should probably read the introduction of a make manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive can't be outside any rule.

You have to create one:

```
mydebug:
        @echo "============= $(TOOLPREFIX) ================="
```

Comment: Then I got:
=================  ===================
TOOLPREFIX :=
make: TOOLPREFIX: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:39: mydebug] Error 127
The output is correct since TOOLPREFIX contains empty string. But what does the following lines mean?

Answer (score 6):

Should not use echo command there. Should use this to print out message:

```
$(info ============= $(TOOLPREFIX) =================)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case $(info bla bla  '$(FOO)') gives an error(missing operator) but
$(warning bla bla  '$(FOO)') works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).