# Snake game makefile

Tags: java, makefile

Trying the make a super simple makefile to compile the two files Board.java and Snake.java. When I use the make command it gives me this error:

```
makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Here's the makefile:

```
Snake.class : Snake.java Board.class
   javac Snake.java;
Board.class : Board.java
   javac Board.java
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makefile:4: \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)

Comment: Nah not really.