# why do i get an error when i try to do $make?

Tags: homebrew, devkitpro, nintendo-3ds

I'm using devkit pro, trying to create a 3DS Homebrew app. I keep getting an error while doing "$make"

I have this code,

```c
#include <3ds.h>

int main(){
gfxInitDefault();
gfxExit();
return 0;
}
```

It just says,

```
\*\*\* missing seperator. stop.
```

I am trying to make the app go to the home menu when started.

So, basically what happened was, I did `$make`, and I expected the files to pop out, and I just got the error instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makefile:4: \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)

Comment: no, mine is "makefile:3: ** missing seperator. Stop."

Comment: @SussyBaka That just means the error is on line 3 of the makefile, rather than line 4.