# Makefile c++: ***missing separator

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to run a program in cpp with the following makefile, but I haven't found a solution for the following error: "Makefile:24: *** missing separator.  Stop."
Does anyone have a suggestion for a solution for this?

```makefile
# Makefile

# Comando padrão para compilação
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall

# Diretórios do projeto
SRCDIR = src
INCDIR = include
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin

# Nome do executável
TARGET = $(BINDIR)/program

# Objetos gerados a partir dos arquivos de código
OBJS = $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/file1.o $(OBJDIR)/file2.o

# Comando para limpar os arquivos gerados pela compilação
RM = rm -f

# Comando padrão para compilação
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

# Regra para gerar os arquivos objeto
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) -c $< -o $@

# Comando para executar o programa
run: $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)

# Comando para limpar os arquivos gerados pela compilação
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(TARGET)

# Comando para limpar tudo e iniciar do zero
reset: clean
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)/* $(BINDIR)/*

# Faz com que a regra "clean" seja executada mesmo que não haja alvo
.PHONY: clean reset run
```

Comment: In makefiles it is ABSOLUTELY ESSENTIAL that you do not mix up your spaces and tabs. all of the instructions in the rules must be indented with tabs, not spaces.

Comment: Start with [makefile:4: *** missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16931770/4581301) and then see if you still have a question.

Answer (score 1):

Those are typically the errors found with Makefile files:

1. Having spaces instead of tabs
2. Not having a final linefeed in the file

Comment: It's not an error to omit the final newline in a makefile.  At least, not for GNU make.  Maybe there are some other implementations of make where it matters.